# Not able to save an item magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, collection

I have a table which store certain data in database.
First i am checking if the content is already there in the database if yes then update it else insert a new data.

```
$sync = $this->inventoryCollection->create()
        ->addFieldToSelect("*")->addFieldToFilter("product_id", ["eq"=>$productId])
        ->addFieldToFilter("type", ["eq"=>$type])->getFirstItem();
    $totQty = $qty;
    $id = 0;
    if($sync->hasData()){
        $invent = $this->inventorySync->create()->load($sync->getData("inventory_track_id"),"inventory_track_id");
        if($invent->getData("sync")){
            $invent->setData("qty", $qty);
        }
        else {
            $totQty = $invent->getData("qty") + $qty;
            $invent->setData("inventory_track_id", $sync->getData("inventory_track_id"));
            $invent->setData("qty", $totQty);
            $invent->setData("product_id", $productId);
            $invent->setData("sync", true);
        }
        $invent->save();
        $id = $invent->getId();
    }
    else {
        $invent = $this->inventorySync->create();
        $invent->setData([
            "product_id" => $productId,
            "qty" => $qty,
            "type" => $type,
            "sync" => true
        ])->save();
        $id = $invent->getId();
    }
```

The strange thing is i am getting an error saying **"Unique constraint violation found"**

How can i update the data?

Comment: please share the  schema of this model

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue.

I had made a small mistake at Resource Class.

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('avesh_inventory_qty_track', ' inventory_track_id');
}
```

It should had been

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_init('avesh_inventory_qty_track', 'inventory_track_id');
}
```

No Spaces.